# How to insert data and tables into an existing one?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a trouble inserting new rows and tables into an already existing one.

Lets call the source *SourceFile.lua* and its simplified contents:

```
SourceFile = {};

SourceFile.list = {
    BrandName1 = {
        number = 10,
        products = {
            "Product1", 3,
            "Product2", 4,
            "Product3", 7,
        },
    },
    BrandName2 = {
        number = 5,
        products = {
            "Product1", 10,
            "Product2", 3,
            "Product3", 6,
        },
    },
    -- and so on
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
require 'SourceFile'

local myData = {
  BrandName2 = { -- add new products for the existing brand
    products = {
      "Product4", 2,
    },
  },
  MyBrandName1 = { -- add new brand
    number = 12,
    products = {
      "MyProduct1", 21,
      "MyProduct2", 95,
    },
  },
  -- and so on
}

table.insert(SourceFile.list, myData)
```

However there's something wrong in my code and I get the following result (printed with [inspect](https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua)):

```
{
  list = { {
      BrandName2 = {
        products = { "Product4", 2 }
      },
      MyBrandName1 = {
        number = 12,
        products = { "MyProduct1", 21, "MyProduct2", 95 }
      }
    },
    BrandName1 = {
      number = 10,
      products = { "Product1", 3, "Product2", 4, "Product3", 7 }
    },
    BrandName2 = {
      number = 5,
      products = { "Product1", 10, "Product2", 3, "Product3", 6 }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new to lua and pretty sure that it's something obvious, but not for me. Please, help me.

---

**Addition**

After these answers I've also found a way to insert new brand names one by one:

```
SourceFile.list.MyBrandName1 = {
    number = 12,
    products = {
      "MyProduct1", 21,
      "MyProduct2", 95,
    },
}
```

This does not fully answer my question, but might be useful to someone new to lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table.insert` adds its second argument to an array (its first argument). Your `SourceFile.list` is only supposed to have string keys, so it can't work as an array. You'll need a recursive function to merge the data from one table into the other:

```
local function meld(data, newData)
  for k, v in pairs(newData) do
    local oldValue = data[k]
    if type(oldValue) ~= 'table' or type(v) ~= 'table' then
      -- One of the values is not a table, so let's clobber the old value.
      data[k] = v
    else
      -- Both are tables.
      meld(oldValue, v)
    end
  end
end

meld(SourceFile.list, myData)
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out to learners that Lua's [Table Manipulation Library](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.6) as a whole is designed to work with sequences, not general tables, and that [sequences](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.7) themselves are an important concept to understand in Lua.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a table of brandnames into a list of brandnames.
Which makes it a list of brandnames + table with brandnames.

```lua
table.insert(SourceFile.list, myData)
```

This inserts `myData` to `SourceFile.list`. `myData` is a table with brandnames.
`SourceFile.list` is also a table with brandnames.
List in list.

You have 2 choices to solve this:

1. Insert each brandname separately
2. Make a function to merge contents of `myData` to `SourceFile.list`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you add an example for the 1st choice, please? I know I can add a product to an existing brandname like that `table.insert(SourceFile.list["BrandName1"].products, "Product4")`. But how to do it with a new table?

Comment: You can't use table.insert for this. `table.insert` is used for sequential arrays. So only numeric keys. You need to use direct insert syntax `tbl[key] = val`